# Organize array of symbols and hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
items = [:one, :two, {three: 3}, {four: 4}, :five, :six]  # => [:one, :two, {:three=>3}, {:four=>4}, :five, :six]

symbols = items.select { |n| n.class == Symbol }              # => [:one, :two, :five, :six]
params = items.select { |n| n.class == Hash }.reduce(:merge)  # => {:three=>3, :four=>4}
symbols << params                                             # => [:one, :two, :five, :six, {:three=>3, :four=>4}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is only Symbols and Hashes in the array you can use [partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) and get the same result with 2 steps:

```
s, h = items.partition {|i| i.class == Symbol}
s << h.reduce(&:merge)
#=> [:one, :two, :five, :six, {:three=>3, :four=>4}]
```

Comment: What is there maybe something else? is there a way to only organize the symbols and hashes?

Comment: user2012677, in that case write `h, s = items.partition { |i| i.class == Hash }` (with no change to the second line).